# How can I get multilabel (not multiclass) classification working for sklearn's log loss metric?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, loss-function, multilabel-classification

I think I'm just not understanding sklearn.metrics.log_loss's API

small code example demonstrating the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics
foo = np.asarray([[0, 0], [0, 1]])

print(sklearn.metrics.log_loss(foo, np.eye(2)))
print(sklearn.metrics.log_loss(foo, foo))
```

which outputs:

```
4.996003610813207e-16
4.996003610813207e-16
```

which doesn't make sense. The y_pred's do not match.

Sidenote, I know the y_pred's are going to be clipped, but that doesn't really change my question. The clipped contribution to the loss is:

```
-np.log(1e-15)
34.538776394910684
```

Comment: Don't you think `foo` should be one dimensional array?

Comment: No, I'm specifically looking at a multilabel problem- one where each record may have more than one label. If you look at the API docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html it says that y_true can be a label indicator matrix. I can't think of any interpretation of that which is consistent except, "Here is an n_samples x n_labels array, where each position is 1 if the sample has that label and 0 if it does not"

Comment: Check out docs carefully, especially expected dimension of y true

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see anything there about the expected dimension of y_true. Are you saying that if they don't specify a shape then I should assume it's just (n_labels)?

Comment: Yeah, okay, looked at the source code. It does seem that they're expecting y_true to be single labels only- they put it through LabelBinarizer, so multi-label stuff won't work.

Comment: Multi-label works indeed, but as probas for y pred

Comment: That's not what multi-label means in the context I'm using it in. It means there are multiple true labels.